# How to find x in a list within a list

Tags: python, list

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,[42,'Meaning of life']]
def some_function('Meaning of life')
# insert code here
return 42
```

How can I do this. Obviously I could find 'Meaning of life' by:

```
for i in a_list:
    if i == "Meaning of life":
        print i
```

Now how can I find the element if it's in a list, and then the element right next to it?

I specifically made my code append everything in that list with the string after the first value or integer.

Comment: What should happen if the target item is at the start of a sublist? The element before the sublist should be returned? What if that element is another sublist? Should the whole sublist be returned or just the last element? (`[1, 2, [3, 4], ["Meaning of life"]]` for example, what should happen there?). This question is badly defined, and the code you have written doesn't even work on the nested lists.

Comment: @Lattyware -- the code posted doesn't work *anywhere* ... If I'm not mistaken, it should raise `SyntaxError` :)

Comment: I specifically made my code append everything in that list with the string after the first value or integer. Is that enough?

Comment: Do you even know what you are trying to do? Do you want your code to magically know which item in a list you are trying to extract? Getting an item in an embedded list is not a problem, return the list with the item you are searching for is not a problem, but having a function return a number 'next to' the item you want, magically, without parameters for doing so... not very possible, try to think about what you are trying to do, ask about that, instead of getting help with what *you* think is a good implementation.

Comment: Although I don't understand your specification, I can tell you probably have the wrong data structure and need to fix that rather than work around it.  Perhaps you could tell us more about your problem.

Comment: Actually a good question would be, why are you working with such an structure?, maybe you could work with a better one (a list of dicts could do...). Just think about how you can organize your data for getting a better work performance. Good Luck.

Comment: In your example, adding variable storing previous element should be sufficient (start with prev None and then if element is not found in current iteration prev=current element. After finding element prev stores element from previous iteration). As many have said here before, we don't know what your data structure look like and what other possibilities your program should accept. Please specify that in your question so anyone could help you find a solution to your problem.

Comment: I posted the wrong code, never mind that. Just please help me with the first part. I tried dictionaries already, but I made a code which stores everything as True and False's. Anyone who knows how a dictionary works, knows that dictionaries assign a value to a single element, and unfortunately I've tried lists got an error; tried sets and failed at that. So I hope I've made myself clearer.

Comment: So sorry I didn't understand tuples at the time >:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> def search(needle, haystack):
        for element in haystack:
            if not isinstance(element, list):
                if element == needle:
                    return True
            else:
                found = search(needle, element)
                if found:
                    return element[0]

>>> a_list = [1,2,3,4,[42,'Meaning of life']]
>>> print search('Meaning of life', a_list)
42
>>> print search('Anything else', a_list)
None
```

Comment: Thank you! :D Finally someone actually gave an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. But I must warn you that this function will work while you maintain the given structure, otherwise it could raise an exception easily. Please have in mind @StevenRumbalski's comment.